# Angular 2.4 -Need working example for Xeditor or Inline editor

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular

Can somebody help me to find good working example for angular 2.4 inline(Xeditor) editor.  I have seen some of the post in github and stackoverflow which does not working for me. Did angular 2x having inline or Xeditor in their package by default?. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. SO contributors are not free coding monkeys. Your question should demonstrate your effort and contain code that shows what you tried, what you try to accomplish, and where you failed.

Comment: Yah.  I have tried below github code for inline editing   https://github.com/qontu/ngx-inline-editor.  Moreover i need to understand from where to start. Whether the functionality already built in as part of Angular package.

Comment: Getting Below error when add inline editor:                             
  compiler.js:466 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'inline-editor'.